# jquery selector without button element

Tags: jquery

All in the `.page-wrapper` should get the `opacity` class -- this works
but the button should stay with opacity 1.

I tried this but it doesn't work (the button is inside the page-wrapper)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".page-wrapper:not('button')").toggleClass("opacity")
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.opacity
{
    opacity:0.4;
}
<button>Toggle class</button>
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SY7Np/
display:none is better for my site instead of opacity:0.0

Comment: If you hide some element containing child elements, also the childs will be hidden..

Comment: This is standard behavior of Opacity. It propagates down and apply the effect to everything inside. Use rgba() instead.

Comment: @NawedKhan means rgba() color for backround.. for example: `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` will give you black background with 50% opacity.

Comment: ok thx $(".page-wrapper").toggleClass("opacity") this works

Comment: but I want all with opacity not only the background-color  how can I edit the button to opacity 1

Comment: Fix your selector to this: `.page-wrapper:not(button)`

Comment: :not(button)  does not work :-( I created a fiddle lol http://jsfiddle.net/SY7Np/ --> the button should stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it you are either missing a space or an ' > '

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
     $(".page-wrapper > :not(button)").toggleClass("opacity")
 });
});
```

additionally you could do, depending on nesting:

```
     $(".page-wrapper :not(button)").toggleClass("opacity")
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SY7Np/1/)

Comment: thx :-) I'm just curious what does the ">" before the :not... ?

Comment: The `>` means only first children, without it will select all children regardless of depth (children, grand-children, grand-grand-children...).

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be:

```
.opacity,
.opacity :not(button) {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SY7Np/2/).

References:

- [`:not()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation).